# How to sort a JSON object in javascript or jquery with the following format

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
"attributes": [
    "BytesServed",
    "Duration",
    "UniqueIPAddresses",
    "StopEvents",
],
"rows": [
    [
        "12118931578714",
        "160557966.305",
        "372",
        "193381",
    ],
    [

        "248313315029",
        "4628315.959",
        "350",
        "27352",

    ],
]
```

I have 2 arrays, where the first array has keys and the second array is a multi-dimensional array with values.

Is there any pre-defined function in Javascript or jQuery which will give me the values in descending order by passing a key?

I have a solution, but I feel that it is a more costly approach. If anybody has better solution please let me know.

My current solution is -- get the index from the first array and loop through the second array and create a temporary array and then sort that temp array and use it.

Comment: It's not valid JSON, you need curly braces around it.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand, you want to specify a key from the first array and sort the second array by that value?

Comment: it is of my opinion that the best solution would be to use `$.makeArray` and `$.map`.

Comment: Yes Terry you are  right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a temporary array. Once you get the index of the attribute you're looking for (and for this example I shall assume it's in a variable called `index` and that the whole JSON object is in `jsondata`), just a simple `sort` will do:

```
jsondata.rows.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a[index]-b[index];
});
```

And there you have your sorted array.